# Ordinary differential equation of order 2, degree 3.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wonder, how could I solve an equation like this?
$y''+(y-\frac{y^3}{6})=0$
Or more general:
$y''+\frac{g}{l}(y-\frac{y^3}{6})=0$

Any hint?

Comment: I would move all the terms to the right side except the $y''$ term and integrate twice to find $y$

Comment: @VarunIyer : How do you evaluate $\displaystyle\int \left(y-\frac{y^3}6\right)\,dx$ (note: $dx$, not $dy$)? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Seems too nonlinear to me to find an exact solution.

Comment: Thre problem with that, Varun Iyer, would be that as we don't know $y$, how could we integrate $y^3/6-y$?

Comment: To all the comments above, my mistake I took he was integrating with respect with $y$.

Comment: DiegoMath, I get $x'=y'-\frac{1}{2}y^2 y'$ and 

$x''=\frac{-1}{2}y''y^2-(y')^2 y+y''$, it seems too complicated.

Comment: For the record, this is a [Duffing Oscillator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DuffingDifferentialEquation.html) and is quite common in textbooks and literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to find a better approximation for the pendulum equation

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = -\frac{g}{l}\,\sin y$$

Follow [this method](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html):

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = f\left(y, \frac{dy}{dx}\right) = -y + \frac{y^3}{6} $$

Let $v = \frac{dy}{dx}$, then $$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dv}{dy} = v \frac{dv}{dy} $$

Which leads to
$$ v\frac{dv}{dy} = -y + \frac{y^3}{6} $$

This equation is seperable. Solving it gives
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = v(y) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{y^4}{12} - y^2 + v_0}$$

Where the constant $v_0 = y'(0)$. This is once again seperable, and the inverse function has the form

$$ x(y) = \int_{y_0}^y \left(\frac{t^4}{12} - t^2 + v_0\right)^{-1/2} dt $$

Where $y_0 = y(0)$. Unfortunately the integral does not have a closed form.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct.

Comment: I've tried to solve this before. There's no closed form as you can see. if you're not against numerical methods, you can do something like [this](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/second/so_num/so_num.html)

Comment: Actually, the function itself doesn't deviate very much from a sine wave, except the period increases with the amplitude. You can replace the small angle amplitude in the approximation with the one given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29#Arbitrary-amplitude_period)

Answer (score 1):

this differential has $$\frac 12 y'^2 + \frac 12 y^2 - \frac 1{24} y^4 = \text{constant} $$
you can solve for $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{E+\frac 1{12}y^4 - y^2}$$
you can separate this, at least numerically, solve for  $y$ in terms of $x.$

Comment: So numerically... Oh. Well, it wasn't what I needed, but if there isn't other way... there isn't other way.